# Android - Log when not connect with Eclipse

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Can i save my app's log when its **`not connect`** with Eclipse using USB?

I want to do this programmatically not using any tool.

I want to save app's log in file or in SDCARD.

It is possible  if yes then how??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below code it may help you :

your main Activity

```
package com.get_Logs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Get_LogsActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        getallLogs();
    }

    private void getallLogs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line+"\n");
            }

            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.doc");
            if (!myFile.exists()) {
                myFile.createNewFile();
            }

            Log.e("log---->", ""+log.toString());

            textv.setText(log.toString());

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(log.toString());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("D: error generate log -->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

your main layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="match_parent"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

your manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.get_Logs"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Get_LogsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can save a log cat with this command

```
logcat -d -v threadtime -f /mnt/sdcard/LogCatApp.txt -s YOURTAG
```

NOTE that you will need to add Log.d("YOURTAG", "info here"); in order to see something, also you can save a full logcat with this

```
logcat -d -v threadtime -f /mnt/sdcard/LogCatApp.txt
```